Postgres query involving join between table and view performs poorly
I have a Postgres query that involves joining a view with a table that isn't performing as expected.
My query is as follows:
SELECT  networks.* FROM "vat"."test_network" net INNER JOIN "vat"."network" networks ON networks."network_id" = net."network_id";
Where test_network is a table with two rows in it:



network_id
vat_return_key




255448
266


388499
266



And networks is a view onto another table called network_nodes. The view DDL is:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "vat"."network" AS SELECT "network_id" FROM "vat"."network_nodes" GROUP BY "network_id";
Where network_nodes is a table with ~9M rows and an index on the network_id column. The network view results in 450k rows.
When I run the explain plan for the initial query it shows me the following:
initial explain plan
Which I think is basically saying that it's reading the full network_nodes table i.e. the full 9M rows?
When directly querying the underlying table network_nodes instead of network it seems to read a lot less rows from the network_nodes table. So when I change the query to:
SELECT  networks.* FROM "vat"."test_network" net INNER JOIN "vat"."network_nodes" networks ON networks."network_id" = net."network_id";
The explain plan is:
updated explain plan
It seems like in my initial query the group by is happening before the join and hence the full table is read? Has anyone got any pointers for how I can speed up this query perhaps by having the join part executed before the group by that is part of the view code?
Apologies if i'm missing any information below, happy to provide any additional information.
Many thanks!

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your query? Also the DDL for all tables, indexes and views involved. All in plain text, not as images.
